# How can I move a file from one location to another?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to move a file from one place to another place. In this case it is my user profile picture. Since I store my user profile picture base on their username, so when they change their username. I will need to move their profile photo, otherwise, the image link will be broken.

I've tried it here:

```
if ( $user->username != Input::get('username')) {
    $new_path = public_path().'/img/logo/'. Input::get('username').'/'.$user->logo_path;
    $old_path = public_path().'/img/logo/'. $user->username.'/'.$user->logo_path;
    $move = File::move($new_path, $old_path);
    $delete = File::delete($old_path);
}
```

---

I keep getting:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the directory exist? And if not, just create it first.

Comment: `delete` is pointless. moving a file will REmove the file from its original location to begin with.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're moving the file in the wrong direction.

It should be `$move = File::move($old_path, $new_path);`

... in other words, the first argument should be the OLD file location, the second argument should be the NEW file location... you have it backwards. :)

From the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/filesystem)

> Move A File To A New Location
>
> Storage::move('old/file1.jpg', 'new/file1.jpg');

Additionally, as said above, you shouldn't have the File::delete either since that file was moved and therefore deleted.

So, two things:

1) Switch the "old_path" and "new_path" and

2) Remove the File::delete line

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you store files based on the user ID instead of username, that way you won't have to move anything when the username changes. Only replace the existing file.