# Laravel move all files directory

Tags: file, laravel

I'm trying to move all the files from one directory to another directory.
I could not do it

```
File::move() ??
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I move file in php Laravel 5 ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811480/how-can-i-move-file-in-php-laravel-5)

Answer (score 2):

Follow this instruction

[Copying a Directory From One Location to Another](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/148/copying-a-directory-from-one-location-to-another)

```
$success = File::copyDirectory($sourceDir, $destinationDir);
```

If you want to move the entire directory and delete source

[laravel move directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40399340/laravel-unable-to-copydirectory-or-movedirectory/40400009#40400009)